# dynamically created radiobuttonlist "not declared"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I am dynamically creating a table which places a dynamically created radiobuttonlist in each row.

I then want to display the results on the page when the submit button is clicked.

I am getting an error message stating that

> 'question1' is not declared

Why might this be happening?? I've included all my code below.

Code behind:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal E as EventArgs)

    For i As Integer = 1 To 3
        Dim TableRow As New TableRow()
        Dim TableRowCell_1 As New TableCell()
        TableRowCell_1.Text = i
        Dim TableRowCell_2 As New TableCell()

        TableRow.Cells.Add(TableRowCell_1)
        TableRow.Cells.Add(TableRowCell_2)
        QuestionnaireTable.Rows.Add(TableRow)

        Dim question As New RadioButtonList
        question.ID = "question" & i
        question.RepeatColumns = "2"
        question.Items.Insert(0, new listitem("", "1"))
        question.Items.Insert(1, new listitem("", "2"))
        TableRowCell_3.Controls.Add(question)
    Next

End Sub

Sub btnSendFeedback_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    Dim question1 As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("question1"), RadioButtonList)
    Dim question2 As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("question2"), RadioButtonList)
    Dim question3 As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("question3"), RadioButtonList)
    Response.write(question1.SelectedValue & " - " & question2.SelectedValue & " - " & question3.SelectedValue)
End Sub
```

Body:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="QuestionnaireTable" />

<asp:Button OnClick="btnSendFeedback_Click" runat="server" Text="Submit..." ID="submitbutton" />
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but when you create your RadioButtonList during the Page_Load event, does it persist between postbacks or is it only there for the initial page load? You may have to be creating it in the Page_Init event. Try just seeing if the control persists between postbacks, because if it doesn't then you can't reference it in your Click function.

Comment: You have to remove the "IsPostBack" too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare your controls in the markup, Visual Studio and ASP.NET make it so that you can access that control in the code-behind.

When you declare a control dynamically like this, *you* have to make accessible from the code-behind.

There are multiple ways to do this, probably the easiest is:

```
Dim question1 As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("question1"), RadioButtonList)
```

Comment: Sorry if DirectCast isn't the right thing to use, my VB.NET is weak.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see you did not declare it any where :)

As "question1" is your ID, you have to find it with FindControl.

```
Page.FindControl(myId)
```

You could define it in the current object for better use, if you have just 3 items.

```
private question1 as RadioButtonList
private question2 as RadioButtonList

Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal E as EventArgs)
     me.question1 = new RadioButtonList
End Sub

Sub btnSendFeedback_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
        dim value = me.question1.selectedValue
End Sub
```

Or you can make something like this

```
private rbls as new List(of RadioButtonList)

Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal E as EventArgs)
     dim list1 as new RadioButtonList
     list.items.add...
     rbls.add(list)
End Sub

Sub btnSendFeedback_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
        For Each _item in Me.rbls
              Response.write(_item.SelectedValue)
        End For
End Sub
```

Comment: This allows the page to load, but not submit. I get the following error -- System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Any Ideas? - that was before you added all the extra info btw, i'll take a look at that now.

Comment: i think my code is alright. NullReference means that you somewhere forgot to say "new" or you are accessing a subobject that is null. But before "click" happens, it always do the "load", always. so if you reach "click", the all your stuff is already there.

Comment: Ah wait a second, you must remove the IsPostBack, otherwise it will not be created on postback!

Comment: OK... so I've updated my code based on what I've got you you guys... Trouble is, in reality there will be a lot more than 3 RadioButtonLists so I wanted to avoid having to declare each one individually . Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah, this is my second method. I like to have them in the list, because you can query them. If you know Linq? querying is a great feature. If you just want to find it by id, it is enough to get the cotnrol by Page.FindControl(myId). with my "list" method you would be able to do something like this: dim selected = from i in me.rbls where i.selectedvalue = "test" select i